# Can a one-dimensional blade cut everything ? (chainsaw) (Sword)

Tags: science-based, technology, nanotechnology

I was thinking in a character who has a...kind of Steam powered Chainsaw, and a sword, what make them special is because the blades of the chainsaw are one-dimensional, same with the sword, they are made of iron.

I was actually curious what could they cut and what not, or anything with that level of edge can cut everything ? and, if that is the case, Could a one-dimensional paper cut with "ease" a Steel spoon ? Or my Iron Chainsaw could cut a armor made of Nuclear pasta ? ((just assuming that somehow someone manage to "deactivate" the gravity that thing should apply over everything, also assuming that material is solid, this is just a crazy totally hypothetical scenario, i actually don't want that kind of armor in my story))

Or be one-dimensional actually would made these thing very fragile ? if that is the case, just the edge part is one-dimensional (With one dimensional i am referring to something with thickness of one atom, only less if is scientifically possible)
I would really appreciate it if someone clarify my doubts, thank you

Comment: Assuming your blade didn't snap, it could, but the cut would be so fine, that the two parts would recombine as soon as the blade was past. For all practical effect, your blade would simply pass through solid objects as though it didn't exist.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2lsgdf/eli5_if_i_made_a_sword_out_of_graphene_what_would/

Comment: Its called a "monomolecular edge". Graphene for example would fit the bill as its a monolomecular structure 1 Carbon atom wide and a lot stronger than steel. Unfortunately the thinner the edge the easier it is to break the edge as well.

Comment: It would be invisible and lighter than a feather: if you get one that works, then better make it a 10 foot pole while at it.

Comment: Chainsaws (or any kind of saw) don't work the same way swords do.  Swords just slice (or stab).  The cutter teeth of a chainsaw cut thin strips of material, and remove the material from the cut.  So a 1-D chainsaw wouldn't work as a chainsaw.

Comment: "One dimensional" is not the same at all as "thickness of one atom".

Comment: they can't be one dimensional and made of iron. an iron atom has three dimensions.

Comment: Even if it was possible to build a one dimensional object with mass (sharp edged or not) - and it isn't you still have the problem that our universe operates at the observable level anyway based on 3 space dimensions plus time. Take any one of the 4 away and from our perspective the object would not exist - we would literally not be able to perceive or interact with it in any way and  vice versa.  So A) you couldn't cut with it. B) you couldn't hold it and C) you couldn't store it anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, assume you have wire that's a single atom wide. You have each atom bonded with only two atoms left and right of it. **If these bonds are weaker than the bonds of the material you want to cut, well, there goes your wire.** As such, no cutting steel with a 1D paper "blade".

Next point is force. You need to supply forward force strong enough to move your "blade" through the material. When you cut something with a wire, all that forward force comes from the wire tension times the curvature of the wire. A straight wire simply cannot have any forward force to cut. The tension of the mono-atomic wire is limited by the strength of its chemical bonds, again. **This puts a strict limit on the width of the material you can cut.** If the material to be cut is to wide, you either cannot apply enough force to push the wire through, or your wire snaps. You may get away with cutting some soft stuff in the range of millimeters, but you won't be able to cut anything macroscopic.

Finally, if you try to cut wet stuff, well that's difficult. Since your "blade" is only separating stuff by the width of a single atom, the wet stuff will just rejoin after the "blade". Thus, **you'll be able to pull your "blade" right through most living cells, and the cell will live on just like nothing happened.** This does not apply to muscle cells where severing the structural proteins would cut the muscle, but your muscle cutting ability is already heavily limited by my second point above. Same story for bones. Anything else should survive your "cut" just fine.

So, bottom line: While a 1D blade sounds very dangerous, it's actually not dangerous at all.

Answer (score 6):

No.
First off, there are no truly one dimensional structures, but if you assume there are:
Cutting requires getting into the material and separating it. You need some sort of wedge for that, the tip digs into the material, and the flanks move the material apart.

Sharpness only helps to some degree, it makes it easier to get some indent for the wedge to move in, but beyond that a sharp edge mostly ensures a cleaner, less jagged cut.

To separate a chunk of metal, you need to provide enough force to drive in the wedge, and move the material out of the way.

Comment: Such a wedge is called a blade. You can't cut glass with a razor blade. Not even if you sharpened the edge to be one atom thick.

Answer (score 6):

A one dimensional thing would be a row of atoms. Think of it like a very thin rope.  it could only work to transmit tension, any other load would make it nonfunctional:

- compression: any tip load would buckle the line, ruining it
- shear: same here, the line would simply bend and be useless

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the blade has the structural integrity to retain it’s shape, it would be useful but could not cut through everything.

Even if the edge of the blade is a single atom thick, [it doesn’t mean it will be able to cut through steel.](https://youtu.be/2L6oFW_L8lw) The blade still has some measure of width, no matter how small, which will mean it will get stuck in the material it is trying to cut through. This is because it has to force apart the steel and push through it but, because of the friction generated, it is likely to get stuck. If the whole blade was this thin, it might cut through steel but, as others have mentioned, wounds caused would not be very thick and might reseal after the blade passes through.

Something else to consider is how long he blade will retain it’s edge. He thinnest edge used on a blade historically was made of obsidian, also called volcanic glass. The edge, if made correctly, [can be a few nanometers in thickness](http://obsidian-scalpel.blogspot.com/2012/12/surgeon-use-for-obsidian-scalpel-blades.html?m=1) (which is so fine you can’t see the very edge with the human eye) but even this can’t cut through steel. The reason being is that, as soon as the blade comes into contact with any material, it will start to dull.

This is true for any material, how well something retains an edge is a key component in the manufacturing of swords. It is also why we aren’t using paper in swords, although it can be very sharp on the edges, it will very quickly dull and won’t have the same level of sharpness. If we assume your blade is made of iron, as stated in the question, it will have a better edge retention but the idea still applies. Whilst it will still be very sharp after the first cut, it will no longer be one-attom sharp.

Answer (score 0):

You need macroscopic thickness, as well as almost-unimaginable levels of strength and toughness to make it work, so no.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding the requirement that the blade be made of "something", **yes**.

Cutting something can be thought of as installing a gap. Most things create this gap by pushing the cut material sideways. But your blade doesn't occupy any space, and so there is no gap. (A cut with no width has no effect.)

So, imagine that the blade is some kind of distortion in the shape of space, so that light followed these paths:

```
    --------------------
---/ /----------------\ \----
----<   "Extra space"  >----
---\ \----------------/ /---
    --------------------
```

This puts "a gap" in the space the material is in, leaves it there for as long as it takes the blade to pass, and then "stitches things back together". This is easily long enough for the material to be hopelessly warped, unless it's exceptionally thick and rigid. You probably can't cut through a mountain, but you would fracture the rock chemical bonds, and might shatter a crystal.

Depending on how this warping is caused, you might be able to swing it with no resistance, or it might be almost impossible to move. Or it would be just as hard to cut with as an "ideal" blade, where you only have to pay the energy cost of disrupting the chemical bonds.

As a side effect, you can keep snacks or a warning sign in the extra space "inside" the blade, which wouldn't be visible edge-on. This can also help in making a scabbard.